# Error in creating C# AMP Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, accelerated-mobile-page

I have created an AMP Page in C#. I am getting the following error in the development mode.

```
The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.
```

I have not given any external scripts for the page.Here is my .cshtml code. Please check it and say why am I getting the error. Thanks in advance
.cshtml Code

```
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Hello, AMP world.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this script is removed,then it will recognize it as amp page

Answer (score 0):

`script` tags are **prohibited** unless the type is `application/ld+json`

Can you try this sample [amp project](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/basic_markup) basic markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the mobile web</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```